# Can I use FSharp.Data with .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, f#

I have Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0. When I try to use FSharp.Data.dll 2.0.9 in my C# project, it gives the warning:

> The primary reference "FSharp.Data" could not be resolved because it
>   has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly
>   "FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.3.0.0"
>   than the version "4.0.0.0" in the current target framework.

**Update:** 
I downloaded and added FSharp.Core version 4.3.0.0 dll to the project reference. It now has one more error message:

> The primary reference "FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not
>   be resolved because it has a higher version "4.3.0.0" than exists in
>   the current target framework. The version found in the current target
>   framework is "4.0.0.0".

Comment: do you have fsharp.core?

Comment: I have it. But the .NET 4.0's FSharp.Core is 4.0.0.0, as the error message says.

Comment: FSharp.Core 4.3 is also for .NET 4.0, just as FSharp.Core 4.0